# Entity framework, abstract class, generic repository and generic manager

Tags: c#, generics, entity-framework-4, abstract-class

In a project, we use generic repository and generic manager so we don't need to rewrite every update / delete etc method in every repository / manager.

Here is how they looks :

```
public interface IBaseRep<T> : IDisposable where T : class, PrivateObject
{
    DbSet<T> DatabaseSet { get; set; }
    DbContext Dal { get; set; }

    T Find(int? id);
    T Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    ICollection<T> Select(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null,
        Expression<Func<T, string>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "");
    T Create(T obj);
    T Update(T obj);
    bool Delete(T obj);
    bool Delete(int id);
    bool Delete(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    IQueryable<T> SelectAsQuery(
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null, 
        Expression<Func<T, string>> orderBy = null, 
        string includeProperties = "");
}

public class BaseRep<T> : IBaseRep<T> where T : class, PrivateObject
{
    public DbSet<T> DatabaseSet { get; set; }
    public DbContext Dal { get; set; }

    public EORTCBaseRep(DbContext dal)
    {
        this.Dal = dal;
        this.DatabaseSet = Dal.Set<T>();
    }

    public virtual T Find(int? id)
    {
        return this.DatabaseSet.Find(id);
    }

    public virtual T Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return Select(predicate).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<T> Select(
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null,
        Expression<Func<T, string>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "")
    {
        return SelectAsQuery(predicate, orderBy, includeProperties).ToList();
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<T> SelectAsQuery(
       Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null,
       Expression<Func<T, string>> orderBy = null,
       string includeProperties = "")
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = this.DatabaseSet;

        if (predicate != null)
            query = query.Where(predicate);

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);

        if (orderBy != null)
            query = query.OrderBy(orderBy);

        return query;
    }

    public virtual T Create(T obj)
    {
        this.Dal.Entry<T>(obj).State = EntityState.Added;
        this.Dal.SaveChanges();
        return obj;
    }

    public virtual T Update(T obj)
    {
        this.Dal.Entry<T>(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
        this.Dal.SaveChanges();
        return obj;
    }

    public virtual bool Delete(T obj)
    {
        if (obj is ILogicallyDeletable)
        {
            this.Dal.Entry<T>(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
            (obj as ILogicallyDeletable).IsDeleted = true;
        }
        else
        {
            this.Dal.Entry<T>(obj).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        }
        return this.Dal.SaveChanges() == 1;
    }

    public virtual bool Delete(int id)
    {
        T obj = Find(id);
        return Delete(obj);
    }

    public virtual bool Delete(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        foreach (T item in Select(predicate))
        {
            Delete(item);
        }
        return this.Dal.SaveChanges() == 1;
    }

    public virtual void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dal.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Our managers looks like this :

```
public interface IBaseManager<T> : IDisposable where T : class, PrivateObject
{
    T Find(int? id);
    T Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    ICollection<T> Select(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null,
        Expression<Func<T, string>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "");
    T Create(T obj);
    T Update(T obj);
    bool Delete(T obj);
    bool Delete(int id);
    bool Delete(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    IQueryable<T> SelectAsQuery(
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null,
        Expression<Func<T, string>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "");
}

public class BaseManager<T> : IBaseManager<T> where T : class, PrivateObject
{
    protected IBaseRep<T> Repository;

    public virtual T Find(int? id)
    {
        return this.Repository.Find(id);
    }

    public virtual T Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return this.Repository.Find(predicate);
    }

    public virtual ICollection<T> Select(
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null,
        Expression<Func<T, string>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "")
    {
        return this.Repository.Select(predicate, orderBy, includeProperties);
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<T> SelectAsQuery(
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null,
        Expression<Func<T, string>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "")
    {
        return this.Repository.SelectAsQuery(predicate, orderBy, includeProperties);
    }

    public virtual T Create(T obj)
    {
        return this.Repository.Create(obj);
    }

    public virtual T Update(T obj)
    {
        return this.Repository.Update(obj);
    }

    public virtual bool Delete(T obj)
    {
        return this.Repository.Delete(obj);
    }

    public virtual bool Delete(int id)
    {
        return this.Repository.Delete(id);
    }

    public virtual bool Delete(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return this.Repository.Delete(predicate);
    }

    public virtual void Dispose()
    {
        if (this.Repository != null)
            this.Repository.Dispose();
    }
}
```

This works well.

But, we now need to use the same DB table for multiple entity type :

```
public abstract class AbstractSite : PrivateObject, IActivable, ILogicallyDeletable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class EthicCommittee : AbstractSite
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
}

public class Site : AbstractSite
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This is how we use the generic managers :

```
public class AbstractSiteManager : BaseManager<AbstractSite>
{
    public AbstractSiteManager (PrismaDAL prismaDAL = null)
    {
        this.Repository = new AbstractSiteRep(prismaDAL);
    }
}
```

and how we use the generic repositories :

```
public class AbstractSiteRep : PrismaBaseRep<AbstractSite>
{
    public AbstractSiteRep (PrismaDAL prismaDAL = null)
        : base(prismaDAL)
    {}
}

public class PrismaBaseRep<T> : BaseRep<T> where T : class, PrivateObject
{
    public PrismaBaseRep(PrismaDAL prismaDAL = null) : base((prismaDAL == null) ? new PrismaDAL() : prismaDAL)
    { }
}
```

But now, we would like to use the concrete types and not the abstract type anymore (AbstractSite = abstract; Site = concrete, RecruitingInstitution = concrete...) without touching the generic repository / manager. So we would have X generic repository (where X : number of concrete types). All of them pointing to the same DB table. 
This would allow us to avoid a cast and allow us to restrict which type we can manipulate using one manager / repository.

Do you, guys, have any idea how i could accomplish this ?

Comment: You should already be able to use concrete types without modifying your generic repository implementation, that's the point of generics.  I think how you decide to map multiple entity types to a single table depends on how you set up your model.  You could possibly use a combination of views and stored procs in your model to make this happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resolved**
My mistake.

This works fine as @Mike C said.

I just didn't know that EF was able to find the correct table if i was referencing a concrete object type instead of the abstract (in TPH).