# TPH Approach Service implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, inheritance

What is the best aproach to develop a TPH based entity with Entity Framework, for example, if I have common fields in an Ads website, and specific ones:

```
public class Ad
{
    // Primary properties
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string TitleStandard { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public string VersionStandard { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public Color Color { get; set; }
    public Member Member { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public IList<Feature> Features { get; set; }
    public IList<Picture> Pictures { get; set; }
    public IList<Operation> Operations { get; set; }
}

public class AdCar : Ad
{
    public int Kms { get; set; }
    public Model Model { get; set; }
    public Fuel Fuel { get; set; }
}

public class AdBoat : Ad
{
    public int Hours { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
}
```

Do I have to build specific operations for every subclass:

- `CreateAdCar()`
- `CreateAdBoat()`

Or can I have something like:

- `CreateAdCommon()` and `CreateAdCar()`

How can I split the two classes so I don't have to repeat all the code for the Car Ad class and Boat Ad class?

Comment: What could be inside your CreateAdCar() and CreateAdBoat() methods ? Is there any logic in those methods ? Flushing new object to database ? Only constructors ?

Comment: Hi, there are some common fields build the same way like the Title or the Price, and other that belong only to the type (car, boat, etc) like kms for the car and hours for the boats

Comment: Yes but what are supposed to do the CreateAdCar() etc ... ? These are manager methods or factory ? If they are supposed to flush a new item in the database, you don't have to worry about that since EF will do everything fine for you. If these are factory method (to instantiate and object), then you will have to take care of it.

Comment: Hi, it's for create a new item in the database but I was trying not to violate the DRY principle, because for the CreateAdBoat I will have to deal with some common fields for example "Title" that is common for CreateAdCar and CreateAdBoat.

Comment: Since you are using EF, you don't have to care about how the "insert/create" is done since EF knows how to map your object to your database table. You only have to add your object to the DbSet and perform a SaveChanges. If it is for the factory, then you can have a method that will receive an Ad as parameter that will take care of the common fields. You then only have to call this method when instanciating concrete types.

Comment: Hi, And do I have to do with every related class? let say CreateAd CreateBoat CreateTruck? or can I have a Create and insert only additional fields for the related entities?